# Grep a list for a word that exists in a line by itself and ignore all other lines that contain that word

Tags: grep

Can a grep command be constructed to so it will return all lines with only a specific word or phrase but won't return any lines that contain the same word or phrase when it contains additional words?  For example, if a list contains:

```
Test
TestNumber2
Test Num 3
Test Nbr4 
Test Random text 
Test with more Random Test data.
What if a Test contains this text?
```

I would like to find a way to return only the lines that contains the single word "Test".  In this case, it would return only line 1.

Comment: What about whitespace before and after the word or lines that don't contain the word at all?

Answer (score 4):

Using anchors, absolutely:

```
$ grep -e '^Test$' <file>
```

Comment: Or `grep -x Test file`

Comment: The OP probably also does not think whitespace is important.